# Why Does a $-string not work in function()

Tags: php, string, function, if-statement

I've read a lot about this, found some nice answers and fixed my problem. but I still don't understand the reason why.

`_check.php` is included on every page to check some things, including if someone is loggen in.
after a lot of checks (if/elseif/else) it ends with:

```
{$chklogin = 'yes'} else {$chklogin = 'no';}
```

when i display this string ($chklogin) on a page, it works perfectly... anything missing in the check and $chklogin displays no. only when all checks are ok it will display yes.
when i put this string in a function...

```
 function login() {
 if($chklogin == 'yes') {return 'J';} else {return 'N';}}
```

the `$chklogin` is still yes, calling the function `login()` returns `N`.
i solved this problem by putting the `$chklogin` in a `$_SESSION`...

```
function login() {
if($_SESSION['chklogin'] == 'yes') {return 'J';} else {return 'N';}}
```

now both`$chklogin` and `$_SESSION['chklogin']` have the same result.

Can anybody tell me why the first function ain't working (the one with `$chklogin`), I really like to understand what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: thanx a lot guys, I still don't understand exactly, but you've send me on the right learning path. Already reading more about globals and passing the value as an argument.
Ithink my question is answered, thanks again!

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language

Comment: Please read about `variable scope` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with scoping. Inside your function, `$chklogin` refers to a *local* variable that is only visible *inside* the function and just happens to have the same name as the *global* variable `$chklogin`.

Try this:

```
function login()
{
    global $chklogin; # use the global variable instead of a local one
    if($_SESSION['chklogin'] == 'yes') 
    {   
        return 'J';
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 'N';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please not `global`.... why not recommend passing the value as an argument to the function?

Comment: because I'm trying to answer OP's question. good point, though. now OP can go and look up best practices to avoid `global`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = ($_SESSION['chklogin'] == 'yes') ? 'J' : 'N';
```

You can use TURNARY operator